# Obj c for loop showing out of scope on variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, loops

I am trying to write a for loop in Obj-c and getting 'out of scope' on my var

```
for ( myObject *i in blah ) {
 i.somevar  <--- i showing out of scope in debug mode.
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `blah`? NSArray?

Comment: Can you provide a real code sample instead of simply saying `i.somevar` is out of scope?  That way, we can actually see what's going on instead of guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myObject` should be `MyObject`;  class names are capitalized in Objective-C.

If you are building for Release, the optimizer is on and it could easily be optimizing away `i`.